# how to manipulate image at pixel level and extract information from image?

Tags: android

How to manipulate image at pixel level. I want to extract information from image by rearranging its pixel. Any help to solve this problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the information from the image you need the below code

```
import android.graphics.Color;

    int[] pixels = new int[myBitmap.getHeight()*myBitmap.getWidth()];
    myBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
    for (int i=0; i<myBitmap.getWidth()*5; i++)
        pixels[i] = Color.BLUE;
    myBitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

Load your image to a bitmap. Then there are functions like

```
Bitmap b = ...
int color = b.getPixel(x,y);
b.setPixel(x, y, color);
```